# Can anyone explain why statements after a cout would change the output?

Tags: windows, cout

The strangest thing is happening.  In the program below, I am printing out one line.  As is, the program outputs the following:

```
-----FOCUS-----:0x22fc80:
```

However, if I comment out any one of the 7 statements after the cout, I get the following:

```
-----FOCUS-----:0:
```

I have included tchar.h, windows.h, iostream and Psapi.h.  I am using MinGW-64 and the command to compile is:

```
"C:\MinGW64\bin\g++.exe" -o MyProgram.exe MyProgram.cpp -lpsapi
```

The program is:

```
int main()
{
    HWND focusThreadWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    DWORD focusThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(focusThreadWnd,0);
    GUITHREADINFO focusThreadInfo;
    GetGUIThreadInfo(focusThreadID, &focusThreadInfo);
    HWND focus = focusThreadInfo.hwndFocus;
    cout << "-----FOCUS-----:" << focus << ":" << endl;

    HWND k1Focus = focusThreadWnd;
    HWND k2Focus = focusThreadWnd;
    HWND k3Focus = focusThreadWnd;
    HWND k4Focus = focusThreadWnd;
    HWND k5Focus = focusThreadWnd;
    HWND k6Focus = focusThreadWnd;
    HWND k7Focus = focusThreadWnd;
}
```

So my questions are, how could commands after a cout affect the output?  And, why does the storage in these seven commands change the output?  And, what is special about 7?

Comment: What if you flush output stream before last 7 lines?

Comment: @SargeBorsch: `std::endl` flushes the stream.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't reproduce your problem, but according to the MSDN page for [GetGUIThreadInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506.aspx)

```
Note that you must set the cbSize member to sizeof(GUITHREADINFO) before calling this function.
```

Those extra 7 HWND affected your stack frame, causing cbSize to be filled with different values